# Syncing query params and state variables in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am fairly new to the `react-redux` environment.

Using [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate.git) for my application.

I am trying to find the right way to sync some redux state variables with query params so that link can be shared with other people.

went through [redux-query-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-query-sync) but it is no longer being maintained.

What I want to sync with the URL query params are the search query string and filters.

Please suggest a good way to implement this in the boilerplate that I am using.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no library to do this I kind of figured my own way hope this helps someone. This is not the **most efficient way** so feel free to suggest me a better one.

**Step 1:** **Catch the state change:**

---

For this all of your related components should be in a singular container and catch the state change using:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (JSON.stringify(prevProps.search.queryString) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.search.queryString)){
       // make sure to use escape to build the queryParams variable
       this.props.history.push(queryParams, null);
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Get the state when the page is refreshed in reducer.js (if you have one)**

---

use a good parser like [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
const params = queryString.parse(history.location.search);
```

**Step 3: Load required state variables on `componentDidMount`**

---

Some state variables are needed to be loaded into the state when that component is mounted you can use `componentDidMount` in that case (if you are getting into one)